# Grauman & Darrells pyramid match kernel - can actual matching be done?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision

I do the project on different matching algorithms, and with this one I can't understand quite clearly - does one really can get pair of corresponding features for train and test image or it just shows the degree of similarity between two images and you can't exactly match them? There are pictures in the article about it claiming some "partial matching", but is is a real matching indeed or not?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a summary based mostly on remembering a paper in CACM, with a few quick looks at http://userweb.cs.utexas.edu/%7Egrauman/papers/grauman_cacm_extended.pdf

Given sets of points Xi and Yi representing features, you can produce a distance as SUM_i d(X_i, Y_p(i)) where p(i) matches each i with its own unique p(i), and is the p(x) producing the minimum such distance. You can find p(x) with the Hungarian algorithm, but this is expensive

The paper shows that you can approximate this distance much more cheaply. The approximation does not provide a p(x) for the original problem, but you *could* (I think) think of it as solving the matching problem for a simplified distance function f(X_i, Y_q(i)) where f(X, Y) only cares about whether X and Y fall into the bin of the histogram at some granularity, and, if so, which granularity that is. The algorithm does not produce an explicit q(x) but I suspect that you could produce one fairly easily if you wanted to, by pairing up points that fell into the same bin. If you did so, I suspect that it wouldn't do too badly with the original distance function d(X, Y), but I don't know what not too badly means here.

The function also has other nice properties, so that it plays well with Support Vector Machines, and fast approximate search algorithms.